# What is the difference between `orange` and `Orange` when importing for the python machine learning package?

Tags: python, machine-learning, orange

Some parts of the docs have `import orange` and others have `import Orange` and they appear to have a different module organization.  What's the difference?

Thanks!

Uri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Orange` is the new top-level namespace introduced in 2.5 to unify the C++-based modules and Python-based modules, which were named as `orange` and `orngXxxx`. See http://orange.biolab.si/blog/2011/12/20/orange-25-code-conversion/ for detail.

Comment: So, the reference documentation is for Orange while the tutorial still uses the older orange organization?  Is this going to be changed soon?